# How to activiti Expressions invoked spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti, flowable

The bpmn file has been deployed to the db.

[activiti Docs](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#exposingConfigurationBeans)

hello.bpmn20.xml shows how a method on a Spring bean can be invoked using a UEL method expression
If the code where the Printer is located  is multi-instance deployment,
all instances are linked to the same database. which one will be called by the bpmn file.
[image]

Comment: hello.bpmn20.xml has bean deployed in DB.

Comment: How activiti with Expressions calls spring beans

Comment: > If the code where the Printer is located is deployed in two places

Please be more specific.

Comment: Need more information/context  about what "deployed in two places" means.

Comment: "deployed in two places"  Means Multi-instance deployment ,But the DB is single